# Flask and Virtual Environment setup

Tags: flask, installation, virtualenv

I am trying to learn flask and python and can't get virtual environment setup.

This is what I did so far

- Create a folder , randomly named it myflask
- Inside the folder I started command prompt and executed the following command
  pip install virtualenv
- then executed following:
  virtualenv myenv -- this created a folder under myflask
- I then ran the following command to activate the virtual environment

  > myenv\Scripts\activate.bat
- and nothing happens, previously I was able to see something similar like
  (myenv) C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\myflask

what am  I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: if you're using bash then type: source myenv\Scripts\activate. If you are using windows command prompts do this cd myenv\Scripts then type activate.